# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to use this code here 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm
but it give me that error. what is the problem? I remove that line but all button are placed on each other in this way.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Alert Dialog"
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:textSize="35dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Tutorialspoint"
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:textColor="#ff3eff0f"
      android:textSize="35dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"/>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="zoom"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:onClick="clockwise"/>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="clockwise"
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:onClick="zoom"/>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="fade"
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:onClick="fade"/>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="blink"
      android:onClick="blink"
      android:id="@+id/button4"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="move"
      android:onClick="move"
      android:id="@+id/button5"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="slide"
      android:onClick="slide"
      android:id="@+id/button6"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Run` & show your full xml

Comment: not works. I add full xml

Comment: Which error you are facing?

Comment: @user3496654 whats your minsdk ?? set 17

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I set it in manifest. not works too.

Comment: @shahzainali the error is written in the title.

Comment: i am trying this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm

Comment: ok i found that it works in android 5

Comment: @user3496654 Problem for API Level

Comment: yes it was for API Level

Comment: my android was 4.0.2 and api 15

Comment: Thats why have problem .Now move ahead .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**layout_alignStart**

> Makes the start edge of this view match the start edge of the given
>   anchor view ID. Accommodates start margin.

**layout_alignStart** is supported from Android 4.2 (API level 17).

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17 // set 19 for best approach
    targetSdkVersion 19 // set 21 for your Requirement

}
```

**Edit**

> To better optimize your app for devices running Android 5.0, set your
>   targetSdkVersion to "21"